# Is it possible to Refresh data in less than 15 minutes in power bi with on premise database

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I'm trying to get real time data in `power bi` via the on `premise gateway`, but the minimum time is 15 minutes to refresh the data, is there any way to refresh the data in real time with an on `premise dataset`?

Answer (score 0):

you can live stream the data into a dashboard using APi.  Here is a link I followed to do my example.  https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-real-time-streaming/